# Angular: bind event based on expression

Tags: javascript, angular

Which function should execute when form is submitted is dependent on whether it is edit mode or not. Is it possible to do something like this in Angular (the code below just throws an error):

```
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="{editMode ? saveUser() : addUser()}" [formGroup]="userForm">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this -

Just remove `{}` sign from the event call like this -

```
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="editMode ? saveUser() : addUser()" [formGroup]="userForm">
```

## [Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j4l6rd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Can you remove the irrelevant first part of your answer?

Comment: That can be used as alternate , isn't it?

Comment: That isn't what the question is about

Comment: NP buddy , I'll remove that part :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   <form novalidate (ngSubmit)="editMode ? saveUser() : addUser()" [formGroup]="userForm">
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. But what you can do is:

```
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="saveUser(editMode ? 'add' : 'save')"[formGroup]="userForm">

saveUser(mode: 'add' | 'save') {
   switch(mode) { .... }
}
```